# How to show sql queue results on data grid based on selected rows of another data grid on VS2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

Here is my code:

```
public void loadGrid1() {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT StudID, Stud_Lname, Stud_Fname FROM STUDENTS;",con);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(), rdr[2].ToString());
                }
                con.Close();
}

public void loadGrid3() {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Title, Author FROM Books INNER JOIN Borrow ON Borrow.BookID = Books.BookID WHERE Borrow.StudID = '"+dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"';", con);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read()) {
                    dataGridView3.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString());
                }
                con.Close();
}
```

`loadGrid1` is the function I used to load contents of `grid 1`, while `loadGrid3` is supposed to show the Books borrowed on `grid 3` by the selected student from `grid 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Debugger is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is susceptible to sql injection. That aside, you might want to check what is the actual query that is getting created here, if at all:

```
SqlCommand(@"SELECT Title, Author FROM Books INNER JOIN Borrow ON Borrow.BookID = Books.BookID WHERE Borrow.StudID = '"+dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"';");
```

perhaps change it to this?:

```
string qryString = @"SELECT Title, Author FROM Books INNER JOIN Borrow ON Borrow.BookID = Books.BookID WHERE Borrow.StudID = '"+dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"';"

SqlCommand(qryString);
```

Edit 1: When is Loadgrid3 method being called?

Edit 2: Try and change the code as follows:

```
public void loadGrid1()
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT StudID, Stud_Lname, Stud_Fname FROM STUDENTS;",con);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(), rdr[2].ToString());
    }

    // check if dataGridView2 has more than 0 rows
    // and then select the first row by default
    if(dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[0].Selected = true
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Remember this is a dirty fix for your immediate question, but you might want to do something with datagridview events etc.

Comment: it is loaded on MainForm_load

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadStudents();
            LoadBooks();
            LoadBorrow();
            
            LoadQuery();
            loadGrid1();
           loadGrid3();
        }

EDIT: I tried the query on sqlexpress and it worked just fine, it shows the title and author of books brrwd by a specific person

Comment: Since this is happening on Form Load and assuming `dataGridView2` has all the data by the time `loadGrid3` is called; are you certain `dataGridView2` has any row selected? Remember this is a fresh load, nothing might needs to be selected.

Comment: Yes I think the selection works fine, I tried displaying its values on textboxes. Do you think it is possible that the loadGrid3() should not be on the main load?

Comment: 'code' private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            x= dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            loadGrid3();
        }
/* It actually worked! Thank you for the idea sir (:*/

Comment: Consider this, you are working on Library Mgmt System (this one looks like one). You displayed all the students. Now, when the user clicks a row in grid an event is triggered that fetches the list of books for that student. If these things are only done in form load there is no scope/use of an event trigger. You will have to handle some sort of select event in the grid and then use loadGrid3.